# Will a user's ChannelId be changed after an App update?

Tags: cordova-plugins, urbanairship.com

We have an old mobile app that based on the Urban Airship Web SDK and soon we are going to release a new version of the same app that uses the Urban Airship Cordova plugin.

Will user's channelId be changed after the update?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely to remain the same if you're using the same Urban Airship project but you should test your user upgrade scenario on both platforms to make sure that's the case. If the push address for the device (iOS device token or the FCM registration token) remains the same during the upgrade then the Urban Airship Cordova plugin should receive the same Channel Id during registration. You might also contact Urban Airship Support as they'll have the best information on how their service behaves.

Comment: Yeah, I've contacted UA Support and they confirm that the Channel ID will stay the same https://support.urbanairship.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115010397246-Will-a-user-s-ChannelId-be-changed-after-an-App-update-

Answer (score 0):

Most probably not. We have been using Urban Airship for last year and the channel IDs of the test devices have never changed by just updating the apps.

Here are some information from the UA documentation stating when the channel-id could be changed

> Native channels are typically backed by an Urban Airship SDK. When a new user runs your app for the first time, our SDK creates a channel to map to that installation. For example, on iOS it will map a device token to that channel. The channel then becomes the primary identifier used to address notifications/messages to the device. If iOS ever changes the device token, we can update the device token behind the scenes without changing the channel.
>
> Native channels can be:
>
> 1- An ID, such as a UUID, e.g., c76ff18e-9cb9-4c19-b9af-a39cae684810.
>
> 2- A push address, e.g., a device token for iOS, FCM registration ID for Android, or ADM registration ID for Amazon.
>
> 3- Metadata, e.g., tags , named users , aliases , quiet time settings, etc.

References:

- experience with UA
- https://docs.urbanairship.com/guides/channels/